# How to write R code to make a matrix transformation

Tags: r

I have a 7x7 matrix and a vector of size 5, and I want to to change the matrix entries to -1 or 1 values according to the following rule:

- if the matrix element matches any value in the vector, it is changed to 1
- if the matrix element doesn't match any element in the vector, it is changed to -1.

In the end I will get a transformed matrix with -1 and 1 values only.

How can I write the R code for this problem?

Comment: Could you make a start on this, and then edit into your question what work you have done? That will make it much easier for readers to help you.

Answer (score 3):

First, I create some example data:

```
m <- matrix(sample(1:10, 49, replace = TRUE),
            ncol = 7)
v <- 1:5
```

This line transforms the matrix according to your specification:

```
m2 <- matrix((m %in% v) * 2 - 1, ncol = ncol(m))
```

`m %in% v` returns `TRUE` for all elements of `m` that are contained in `v` and `FALSE` for all the others. If arithmetic is done with logical variables in R, `TRUE` is converted to 1 and `FALSE` to zero. Therefore,

```
TRUE * 2 - 1 = 1 * 2 - 1 = 1
FALSE * 2 - 1 = 0 * 2 - 1 = -1
```

The result of the computation is a vector, which again must be converted to a matrix using `matrix()`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the same data as @stibu:

```
m[]<-ifelse(m %in% v,1,-1)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    1   -1   -1    1    1   -1
[2,]    1   -1   -1   -1    1   -1   -1
[3,]    1   -1    1   -1   -1    1    1
[4,]    1    1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[5,]    1   -1   -1    1   -1    1    1
[6,]    1   -1   -1    1   -1    1   -1
[7,]    1   -1   -1   -1    1    1    1
```

On a side note, Stibu's solution is faster (using a dataset with 7000 rows):

```
microbenchmark(stibu=matrix((m %in% v) * 2 - 1, ncol = ncol(m)), iod=matrix(ifelse(m %in% v,1,-1),ncol=ncol(m)))
Unit: microseconds
  expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
 stibu  441.5  447.25  574.993  450.95  462.20 5352.2   100
   iod 1070.6 1080.70 1363.861 1113.50 1154.45 4974.5   100
```

but I think mine is more generalizable if you don't need 1 and -1 as the output but something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code

```
m[]<- 2*(m %in% v)-1
```

where `m` is the 7-by-7 matrix, and `v` is the vector of size 5.

**Example**

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(49),nrow = 7)

> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    4   18   15   38    6   16   32
[2,]   39   33   48   41   28   19    8
[3,]    1   21   25   12   45   17   29
[4,]   34   40   44   35   46   36   22
[5,]   23   10    5   47   27   37   13
[6,]   43    7   31   20   49   42   30
[7,]   14    9    2    3   26   24   11

v <- sample(5)
> v
[1] 2 1 5 3 4
```

and you will get

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[2,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[3,]    1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[4,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[5,]   -1   -1    1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[6,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
[7,]   -1   -1    1    1   -1   -1   -1
```